# Does sklearn.pipeline have a single mechanism for cross-validation regardless of model API?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, pipelines

With a single standard interface (sklearn.pipeline) on top of different regressors, how do I use cross-validation?

The example below uses two regressors *with different internal cross-validation mechanisms*, and I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way to do this without resorting to calling each differently.

```
import catboost as cb
import numpy as np
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
import sklearn.pipeline
import sklearn.preprocessing

# *************************************
# First, the common code
# *************************************

# Build x and y
# y is a simple linear function (with noise added)
x = np.arange(100)
y = x * 10 + 4 + np.random.random(len(x)) * np.random.binomial(len(x), 0.5)

# We only have one "feature" so this is needed to make the regressors happy
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)

# Split into train/test in preparation for cross-validation
x_train = x[:80]
x_test = x[80:]
y_train = y[:80]
y_test = y[80:]

# *************************************
# Exhibit A
# Cross-validation using e.g., CatBoost
# (Yes I know gbm isn't a great choice
# for this dataset, just ignore that
# for now)
# *************************************

pipeline = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('scaler', sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('model', cb.CatBoostRegressor())
])

pipeline.fit(
  x_train, 
  y_train, 

  # Tell CatBoostRegressor to use cross-validation
  # Pipeline lets me funnel params to the 'model' component
  # which is in this case a CatBoostRegressor
  model__eval_set=(x_test, y_test)
)

# *************************************
# Exhibit B
# Cross-validation using e.g., Keras
# *************************************

# Helper function for pipeline to create the model
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units = 1, input_dim=x_train.shape[1]))
    model.add(Dense(units = 4))
    model.add(Dense(units = 1))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return model

pipeline2 = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('scaler', sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('model', KerasRegressor(model=create_model))
])

pipeline2.fit(
  x_train, 
  y_train, 

  # We have to use another funnel-though that is
  # completely different to turn on CV for Keras
  model__validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
)
```

So my question is:

Can I use Pipeline API to activate cross-validation across these two (or any other) model types *using the same call to fit()*?

```
Exhibit A = pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train, <Pipeline way to activate cv>)
Exhibit B = pipeline2.fit(x_train, y_train, <Pipeline way to activate cv>)
```

are identical?

Comment: Can you describe your issue in a bit more detail? Is the issue that the results are different or that different keyword arguments are used within the `fit` method depending on the type of model used?

Comment: It's the latter.  The keywords are different (to enable CV).  For example, pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train, model__eval_set=(x_test, y_test)) and pipeline2.fit(x_train, y_train, ????).  The eval_set=() argument does not work for KerasRegressor.

Comment: There's a larger concern here as well, which is that the StandardScaler() is applied only to x_train (which is correct -- we don't want forward bias!) but I would like the SAME scaler, fitted to x_train, to be applied to x_test.